# array get the same records

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to create a function in which I can pass a record set which is an array, and then it will line up all the manufacturers in a country and return back the redone array

my record set is

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufecturer] => Honda


                    [MID] => 584
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Japan
                )

        )

[1] => Array
         (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufecturer] => Toyota


                    [MID] => 531
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Japan
                )

        )


[2] => Array
         (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufacturer] => KIA


                    [MID] => 532
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Korea
                )

        )

[3] => Array
         (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufacturer] => BMW


                    [MID] => 534
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Germany
                )

        )

[4] => Array
         (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufacturer] => Mercedece


                    [MID] => 543
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Germany
                )

        )

[5] => Array
         (
            [Cars] => Array
                (
                    [Manufacturer] => SAAB


                    [MID] => 523
                )


            [Chracterstics] => Array
                (

                    [Country] => Sweden
                )

        )
```

In ideal situation I would get an array back.

**EDIT**
for example

```
[Japan] => Array
    (
       [0] => Array(
                   [Manufacturer] => Honda
                   ) 
       [1] => Array(
                     [Manufacturer] => Toyota
                   ) 
     )

[Sweden] => Array
    (
       [0] => Array(
                   [Manufacturer] => SAAB
                   ) 

     )
```

thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you want the result to look like.

Comment: >In ideal situation I would get an array back Its not clear what you are asking, as you already have the data in arrays. If you can tell us exactly what result you are looking for, we might be able to offer more help. Also, where are you getting the recordset from, e.g. are you running a query on the database? If so, what is the query, as it may be more efficient to do this through your SQL query.

Comment: well I guess I just need to rearrange this record set meanning getting something like 
[Sweden] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array([Manufacturer] => Saab ) 
         )

Comment: Can you tell us the SQL you use to get the recordset please? As I said, it may be more efficient to pull it from the database in a more suitable format.

Comment: I dont have the SQL. ALl I have is the recordset coming back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. Obviously it's very simple and doesn't deal with duplicates and assumes you're looking for the manufacturer name rather than the ID but I'll leave that to you unless you want to update your requirements.

```
function getManufacturerByCountry($array) {
    $results = array();
    foreach ($array as $tmp) {
        $results[$tmp['Chracterstics']['Country']][] = $tmp['Cars']['Manufacturer'];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To prevent duplicates,

```
foreach ($array as $tmp) {
    $country = $tmp['Chracterstics']['Country'];
    $manufacturer = $tmp['Cars']['Manufacturer'];
    // Only add manufacturer if new country or if manufacturer isn't in country array.
    if (!isset($results[$country]) || !in_array($manufacturer, $results[$country])) {
        $results[$country][] = $manufacturer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't deal with the inconsistencies in the input array (e.g. 'Manufacturer' vs 'Manufecturer')

Comment: yea inconsistencies isnt a problem. I can check for that. How would I make sure that there is no duplication of Manufacturer. Can I use the id? Howd I go about it

Comment: Updated to prevent duplicates.